# A space $X$ is path connected if and only if there is a point $a$ in $X$ such that each point of $X$ can be joined to $a$ by a path in $X$.

Tags: general-topology

A space $X$ is path connected if and only if there is a point $a$ in $X$ such that each point of $X$ can be joined to $a$ by a path in $X$.

I'm trying to prove this statement. The only if direction is trivial by the definition of path connectedness. To prove the converse direction, I'm trying to use this lemma.

Lemma: Let $X$ be a space and ${A_\alpha: \alpha \in I}$ a family of path connected subsets of $X$ for which $\bigcap_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$ is not empty. Then $\bigcup _{\alpha \in I}$ $A_\alpha$ is path connected.

Then we can think of a family of path connected subsets ${A_x : x \in X}$, where each members of the family is a path from $a$ to $x$. Then the union of the family would be $X$ and is path connected by the preceding lemma.

I think this proves teh first statement but I can't come up with the proof for the lemma above. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You don't need to use the lemma, one way to do it would be by proving that two points being connected by some path is an equivalence relation (the important point here being transitivity).

Comment: I would say that *if* direction is trivial, because being connected by a path is obviously transitive. I'm not sure why you think the *only if* direction is trivial.

Comment: How can I show that two points being connected by some path is transitive?

Comment: @user135204 Visualize it. There's a path from $A$ to $B$ and one from $B$ to $C$. Don't you see the obvious path from $A$ to $C$? Now you just need to express that path formally.

Comment: A good part of the solution is here
http://uregina.ca/~franklam/Math535/Math535_1022.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Joining two paths, say $p_1$ and $p_2$ gives you another path which can be given by $p$ where

$$ p \left({s}\right) = \begin{cases}
p_1 \left({2s}\right), &  s \in \left[{0 , \dfrac 1 2}\right] \\
p_2 \left({2s - 1}\right), &  s \in \left[{\dfrac 1 2 , 1}\right]
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Is that the proof?

Comment: Clearly p(s) is continuous,since interval are connected